# cannot download Image processing toolbox in SCILAB 2023

Tags: scilab

I am not able to download image processing toolbox in Scilab 2023.
Whereas it works perfectly in Scilab 6.1.
in Scilab 2023 while installing the image processing tool package, it throws a Atoms error like installation failed.
Is there any other way to install package in Scilab 2023 or am I going wrong any where?
Please can any one help me out with this!

Comment: What is the exact name of the Atoms package you are trying to install ?

Comment: image processing tool

Comment: I meant the *exact* name of the atoms package. "image processing tool" is not the name of an atoms package.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with Image Processing and Computer Vision Toolbox 4.5.0 on Scilab 2023. After updating to Scilab 2024.0 the toolbox installed just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).